# tilegrid problems

Tags: java, smartgwt

I use TileGrid from smartgwt. TileGrid contains 300 records. I select, for example, 150 record and move on to another page. In this TileGrid placed in Canvas, and Canvas in the model. When I go back to the previous page, the drawing Canvas (and TileGrid) from the model. TileGrid shows the first line, but if you use the mouse scroll then TileGrid positioned on the record that was selected earlier. How do I make it with a return to the old page immediately positioned on an old record

method "getCentr(false)" contains abstract method "getElement()". Methods "getShapka()","getPodval()" return Vlayout. Class NewHolst is template view.

```
public class VakansiSearchLayout extends NewHolst{
private List<ProfessiaBean> profBean = new ArrayList<ProfessiaBean>();
private List<ProfessiaBean> profBeanBufer = new ArrayList<ProfessiaBean>();
private VLayout content;
private TileGrid tileGrid;

public VakansiSearchLayout(MenuItem curentMenuItem, INotifier notifer)
{
    super(curentMenuItem, notifer);
    if (ModelVakansi.INST.getBuffer() == null)
        poluchitProf();
    else
    {
        content = (VLayout) ModelVakansi.INST.getBuffer();
        tileGrid = (TileGrid) content.getMember(0);
    }
    {
        addMember(getShapka());
        addMember(getCentr(false));
        addChild(getPodval());
    }
    if (ModelVakansi.INST.getBuffer() != null)
    {
        ModelVakansi.INST.setBuffer(null);
    }
}

private void poluchitProf()
{
    addDrawHandler(new DrawHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDraw(DrawEvent event)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SGWTRPCServletWithProgress.run(new Callback<List<ProfessiaBean>>()
            {
                @Override
                public void run(List<ProfessiaBean> result)
                {
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        if (result.isEmpty())
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            profBean = result;
                            content.removeMembers(content.getMembers());
                            content.addMember(lookProf());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GuiContextInst.getInst().showWarn("Error");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void error(Throwable caught)
                {
                    check(caught);
                }

                private void check(Throwable caught)
                {
                    runError(caught);
                }
            }, "wait", Actions.PROF, "");

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected Canvas getElement()
{
    if (ModelVakansi.INST.getBuffer() != null)
    {
        // content = (VLayout) ModelVakansi.INST.getBuffer();
        return content;
    }
    else
    {
        content = new VLayout();
        content.setWidth100();
        content.setHeight(centrHght+20);
        content.setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);
        content.addMember(lookProf());
        content.setScrollbarSize(0);
        return content;
    }
}

private Canvas lookProf()
{
    tileGrid = new TileGrid();
    tileGrid.setWidth(centrWdth + centrBlock);
    tileGrid.setHeight(centrHght+20);
    tileGrid.setTileWidth(370);
    tileGrid.setTileHeight(92);
    tileGrid.setStyleName("label_prof");
    tileGrid.setCanReorderTiles(true);
    tileGrid.setCanFocus(true);
    tileGrid.setShowAllRecords(false);
    tileGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);
    tileGrid.setAnimateTileChange(true);
    tileGrid.setData(getRecords());
    tileGrid.setWrapValues(true);
    tileGrid.setScrollbarSize(0);
    tileGrid.setBorder("0px");
    tileGrid.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            ModelVakansi.INST.setBuffer(content);
            notifer.notifyListeners(new Event(ru.my.web.client.Event.SELECT_PROF,
                    tileGrid.getSelectedRecord().getAttributeAsObject("code").toString()));
        }
    });

    DetailViewerField name = new DetailViewerField("name");
    tileGrid.setFields(name);
    tileGrid.sortByProperty("name", true);

    return tileGrid;
}

private ProfRecord[] getRecords()
{
    int i = 0;
    ProfRecord result[] = new ProfRecord[profBean.size()];
    for (ProfessiaBean oneProfe : profBean)
    {
        result[i] = new ProfRecord(oneProfe.getName().toUpperCase(), oneProfe.getCode());
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public void scrolToIframe(String id, int i)
{
    tileGrid.scrollBy(0, i);
}}
```